# Invalid Path using XCOPY

Tags: windows-7

Writing script to backup selected directories from my hard drive (C:) onto an external hard drive using XCOPY.

All went well when I used the same directory name on both source and destination. But when I tried to get a bit clever and 
make the destination a subdirectory of a dated main directory called "Archive", I keep getting an "Invalid path" error.  Here's an exerpt 
of what I'm trying to do:

```
set/P Drive= Enter destination drive (with colon):
:: 
set BACKUPCMD= xcopy /S /D /I /Y /Q /C /T
:: 
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%"==" " set hour=0%time:~1,1%
SET dateNtime=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2   %__%hour%:%time:~3,2%       
::
set directory=TEST
set source=%directory%
set destination=%Drive%\ARCHIVE_%dateNtime%\%directory%

%BACKUPCMD% "C:\%source%\*.*" "%destination%"
```

Could somebody help me with my syntax?

Comment: Does `dateNtime` have spaces in it?  Does the string contain any characters that would make it an invalid directory?

Comment: -3--%date~7,2   %__1904 is the final output of the dateNtime. This has invalid windows names. Also it has spaces as @Ramhound mentioned, so it needs quotes

Comment: *The alternative is to fix the generated string.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Could somebody help me with my syntax?

There are several problems with your batch file:

1. The options to xcopy go **after** the source and destination

   ```
   XCOPY source [destination] [options]
   ```
2. Your `SET dateNtime...` command is broken.

   - It contains spaces and trailing spaces.
   - Using `%date%` to provide a solution is dependent on the OS Locale, Regional, and Language settings.
   - Rather than try and fix your code I've provided working code using  `wmic` (see [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html))
   - This code works independently of OS Locale, Language or the user's chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional) and it is very easy to change the output format.

The following batch file fixes both of these issues:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set/P Drive= Enter destination drive (with colon):
:: 
set BACKUPCMD=xcopy
SET BACKUPOPTIONS=/S /D /I /Y /Q /C /T
:: 
rem get date independently of OS Locale, Language or the user's chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%g in (`wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _day=00%%g
  set _hours=00%%h
  set _minutes=00%%i
  set _month=00%%j
  set _seconds=00%%k
  set _year=%%l
  )
rem pad with leading zeros
set _month=%_month:~-2%
set _day=%_day:~-2%
set _hh=%_hours:~-2%
set _mm=%_minutes:~-2%
set _ss=%_seconds:~-2%
rem adjust _date as appropriate for your requirements
set _date=%_year%%_month%%_day%%_hh%%_mm%%_ss%
::
set directory=TEST
set source=%directory%
set destination=%Drive%\ARCHIVE_%_date%\%directory%

echo %BACKUPCMD% "C:\%source%\*.*" "%destination%" %BACKUPOPTIONS%
```

Notes:

- I'm not sure from your question exactly what date format you are looking for.
- Change `set _date=%_year%%_month%%_day%%_hh%%_mm%%_ss%` as appropriate to get your required date format.
- Remove the last `echo` when you are happy with the `xcopy` command.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html) - Display the date and time independent of OS Locale, Language or the users chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer.  However, I'm still having a problem.  I'm not sure how to ask a further question with an example, so I'll make a new post.  Thanks again.  Paul