# Still having difficulties with XCOPY

Tags: windows-7

Thanks to this answer [Invalid Path using XCOPY](https://superuser.com/a/1057234/337631) by [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill), I've gotten things a bit better:

```
set/P Drive= Enter destination drive (with colon):
echo %Drive%
:: 
set BACKUPCMD=xcopy 
set BACKUPOPTIONS=/S /D /I /Y /Q /C /T 
:: ----------------------------------------------
:: Use WMIC to retrieve date and time
::
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get   Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
  Set _year=%%L
  Set _month=00%%J
  Set _day=00%%G
  Set _hour=00%%H
  SET _minute=00%%I
)
:s_done

:: Pad digits with leading zeros
  Set _month=%_month:~-2%
  Set _day=%_day:~-2%
  Set _hour=%_hour:~-2%
  Set _minute=%_minute:~-2%

Set _date=%_year%-%_month%-%_day% %_hour%:%_minute%
Echo point 1 %_date%
pause
::
:: _______Backup Operations _______________________
::
set directory=TEST
set source=%directory%
set destination=%Drive%\ARCHIVE_%_date%\%directory%

echo %BACKUPCMD% "C:\%source%\*.*" "%destination%" %BACKUPOPTIONS%
echo point 2
%BACKUPCMD% "C:\%source%\*.*" "%destination%" %BACKUPOPTIONS%
echo point 3
```

Here's what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The colon (":") in the time stamp is an invalid character in a path component after the drive letter (for obvious reasons). I'd cut it out entirely to make it suitable in a path.

Answer (score 0):

#### Still having difficulties with XCOPY

```
Set _date=%_year%-%_month%-%_day% %_hour%:%_minute%
```

...

```
set destination=%Drive%\ARCHIVE_%_date%\%directory%
```

You are trying to create a directory name containing a `:` character. That is not allowed.

You cannot use any of the following reserved characters as part of a directory or file name:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

You need to think of another way to name your target directory.

---

#### Naming Conventions

> The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and
>   process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file
>   system:
>
> - Use a period to separate the base file name from the extension in the name of a directory or file.
> - Use a backslash (`\`) to separate the components of a path. The backslash divides the file name from the path to it, and one directory
>     name from another directory name in a path. You cannot use a backslash
>     in the name for the actual file or directory because it is a reserved
>     character that separates the names into components.
> - Use a backslash as required as part of volume names, for example, the `C:\` in `C:\path\file` or the `\\server\share` in
>     `\\server\share\path\file` for Universal Naming Convention (UNC)
>     names. For more information about UNC names, see the Maximum Path
>     Length Limitation section.
> - Do not assume case sensitivity. For example, consider the names OSCAR, Oscar, and oscar to be the same, even though some file systems
>     (such as a POSIX-compliant file system) may consider them as
>     different. Note that NTFS supports POSIX semantics for case
>     sensitivity but this is not the default behavior. For more
>     information, see CreateFile.
> - Volume designators (drive letters) are similarly case-insensitive. For example, "D:\" and "d:\" refer to the same
>     volume.
> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>     (128–255), except for the following:
>
>   The following reserved characters:
>
>   ```
>       < (less than)
>       > (greater than)
>       : (colon)
>       " (double quote)
>       / (forward slash)
>       \ (backslash)
>       | (vertical bar or pipe)
>       ? (question mark)
>       * (asterisk)
>   ```
>
>   - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
>   - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1  through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>       are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>       Streams.
>   - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.
> - Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the current directory, for example ".\temp.txt". For more information, see
>     Paths.
> - Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory component in a path to represent the parent of the current directory, for example
>     "..\temp.txt". For more information, see Paths.
> - Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
>   CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8,
>     COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also
>     avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example,
>     NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces.
> - Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the
>     Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable
>     to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example,
>     ".temp".

Source [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a novice.  If I can't use a colon, how can I identify a drive in my xcopy arguments?

Comment: @Paul_NJ `:` is allowed **only** in the drive part of the directory name not anywhere else (like in the middle where you have it)..